# Number of web socket clients that could be opened at once

Tags: c#, sockets, websocket, owin

I am simply looking at the sample code found [here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#Samples/Katana/WebSocketSample/SampleClient/Program.cs):

When I run the server portion and start multiple instances of the client I notice that when I start around 40-50 of them at the same time (using Process.Start()) that sometimes some clients fail to connect.

Why does this happen? What actually stops all these clients from connecting at once? Is there a request limit hidden somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the limitation is not on the server?

I use [ClientWebSocket to do some simplistic stress test](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/wiki/WebSocketListener-performance-tests) on my WebSocket component and I can reach thousands or connections and almost a 100% throughput of my NIC. However, I do not create a process for each call. You can see the test console app source code or just download the executable [here](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketEchoLoadGenerator).

Comment: Quite possible will look into that route. Thanks for the source.